# Where is the best place to farm Blood Vials in Bloodborne?

Tags: bloodborne

I went back to playing Bloodborne on PS4 after a 10 month break. I just made it past Rom the spider thingy, and now I'm out of blood vials, which doesn't help moving further in the game. I also don't quite remember the previous other areas of the game, so I'm not sure where I could get a good amount of blood vials.

Where would be the best place to farm for blood vials? If I can get blood echoes at the same time, it would be best. I am level 50 at the moment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my opinion, the safest, fastest way to acquire blood vials at this point in the game is to buy them, even though they cost 720 echoes each after fighting Rom.

Many of the blood vial farming runs suggested online are quite good, netting 15-20 vials per run; however, if you aren't careful, they'll net you much less than that, as you'll have to use some to survive against the more difficult enemies (e.g. Hemwick executioners, giant hogs, scourge beasts). You can avoid this issue by farming for echoes in a safer, more predictable environment, then buying blood vials with the echoes you've earned.

The first floor of the Lecture Building is a great blood echo farm, consisting only of Slime Scholars (a relatively non-threatening enemy), and the run will net you around 13K-15K echoes -- enough to buy 18-20 vials. The Slime Scholars also have a chance to drop Quicksilver Bullets and Sedatives, both of which are nice to have in large quantities.

To summarize, I suggest farming the first floor of the Lecture Building for blood echoes to buy vials, because:

- The run is much safer than most blood vial farming runs
- The run takes around the same amount of time to complete as a blood vial farming run
- The blood echoes you get allow you to purchase a number of blood vials comparable to that of a blood vial farming run

I understand that this technically doesn't answer the question of "Where is the best location to farm blood vials?", but it does help the asker with their stated issue, and the end result is the same.

Comment: Interesting. Is the first floor of the Lecture Building really that lucrative? I think that is the area I spent the least amount of time in, really. I'll have to check that out the next time I play.

Comment: @Vemonus I never spent much time in it either, given that it's somewhat boring. I started second-guessing my memory after seeing your comment, so I loaded it up just now to make sure. On NG, without any moon runes equipped, the run gave me 15,174 blood echoes. Better than I remembered :D

Comment: I don't think I have reached that place yet, I'm in Yahar'Gul

Comment: @jgadoury Ah, I didn't realize. You can access it at any time after the Forbidden Woods. Any chance you talked to someone at a red lantern window who gave you an item called the Tonsil Stone? I won't spoil things unless you want me to, but that item is the key.

Comment: I'll take a look at my inventory tonight, I've definitely talked to a couple of NPCs through doors/windows. I still don't know where the Lecture Building is, but that's all right, I want to find it by myself :)

Comment: @jgadoury I definitely understand -- these games are about exploration and discovery, and taking that away by spoiling things for people is a huge bummer. Best of luck, and may the good blood guide your way.

Comment: All right, I found the Lecture Building, and as you say the enemies in there are very easy to kill. I will mark this as the accepted answer

Comment: @jgadoury Yay! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

The place I use the most for Blood Vials is in Central Yharnam. Luring the werewolves to the two-story house that leads to the bridge where you fight Cleric Beast is the lowest-risk farming location. Each werewolf should drop 2-3 Blood Vials when they do drop them (they have a high drop rate), but they cannot come into the house as they are too big. There are other enemies in the house which you should be able to one-shot at this point, and some may drop additional Blood Vials. It's worth noting that this is also quick and easy way to farm Quicksilver Bullets, as the Wheelchair Hunter drops a set 4 bullets each time you kill him and he has his back towards you when you enter the house. Overall, this route should guarantee you 4 Quicksilver Bullets and 3-6 Blood Vials (potentially more) every couple of minutes. Personally, I prefer this route due to the fact that you have virtually no risk of dying and it's extremely quick.

If you are looking for a challenging route, I might suggest Cainhurst Castle, though, according to the [wikia](http://bloodborne.wiki.fextralife.com/Cainhurst+Castle), the recommended level is 60-80, so it may be too difficult for you at the moment. That and it will take a lot longer than the previous method. Also, if memory serves, the enemies won't drop Blood Vials too terribly often. However, the route is relatively easy and you will receive ample Blood Echoes, with which you can *buy* a lot of Blood Vials.

According to [this wikia page](http://bloodborne.wiki.fextralife.com/Farming), there is an alternate recommended route:

> Warp to the Witches' Abode lamp and head straight back toward the first Hemwick Charnel Lane lamp killing everything along the way. The three axe guys yield about 2500 echoes apiece, and at night there are two smoke demons worth 1500 ( the second smoke demon spawns just outside the entrance to the Hemwick area). One run nets about 15k echoes with the first tier Moon rune equipped.

Comment: I tried this farming method, it works pretty well and is early in the game. Thanks

Comment: @jgadoury, yeah it may be a bit slower and kind of boring but it is very low-risk, which is a rarity in a game like Bloodborne :P

Comment: Central Yharnam is the method I use as well but after your description I kill the two Huntmen's Minions, take the elevator to the second bridge. Then, kill everything (including the Man Eating Pig with a trivial visceral attack) and head to the Tomb of Oedon lamp. It takes around ten minutes and nets me around 20 to 30 blood vials. If I die, I just repeat from the closest lamp where I died. *Clearly, do not use any blood vials on these runs.* Yes, you lose a tiny amount of blood echoes. Meh.

Answer (score 3):

The good route is from Father Gascoigne fight lamp backwards, across the bridge (or trigger ball, which will fall just at enemies on bridge, and go under bridge), use shortcut elevator, and go to Cleric Beast lamp. 4 giant huntsmen, several big mutated hunters, 2 beasts, numerous common huntsmen, 1 giant hog. I'm getting around 10-15 vials per run in such route.

Giant hogs in last part of Forbidden woods are also granting big amount of vials.

Comment: This a very good one, I see the advantage of being able to use it since almost the beginning of the game.

Answer (score 0):

All of these places are reasonable places to farm blood vials but in my oppinion forbidden woods is the best place. I am doing a casual run now after being away from the game a while focusing on DS3.

Reason behind forbidden woods is i am blood level 76 on the first run and have completed every boss except Micolash and Gerhman. Lost most of my blood vials to Rom. If you can beat Rom you are well capable of beating all the enemies in forbidden woods in terms of level. The main reason Rom is difficult is crowd control which applies in FW. Take each enemy on 1 on 1 and do to runs of the forest and you have 100,000 blood echoes and a good amount of blood vials farmed then just buy what other quantity you need.

My oppinion the best way hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The best (quickest) farm spot is a small run in forgotten woods. You get 14k and around 10 blood vials really quickly. 
You don’t even have to travel back to the dream to do it again!

From the lantern go up the hill kill the two enemies and the fat axe guy. Then progress normally until you get to the area with all the bonfires and 2 dogs. Kill these enemies. 
Now do blood bullets and fire one shot. Repeat until health is low. Walk into the fire and die. Repeat. Make sure to get your echoes before your next suicide. 
You do this because the death load screen is quicker than the 2 travel load screens to and from hunters dream

Answer (score 0):

Heres my best option. Start your run from Oedons Tomb and go via the aquaduct with the pig without missing the Executioner to the great Bridge lamp. If you clear all the enemies it should give you about fifteen vials. Do a second run and then spend the echoes on Blood vials netting a total of almost fifty vials in about fifteen minutes.