# Why is there a baby crying in Bloodborne?

Tags: bloodborne

I'm currently at Cainhurst Castle and for a while now, I've been hearing a faint baby crying in the background. I seem to be hearing it anywhere I go. It also seems to have started when the Blood Moon showed up, but I'm not sure.

Without telling me any spoilers, can anyone tell me why there is a baby crying in the background all of a sudden? Is it something story-related that I'll eventually understand, or is it due to some item I might have picked up?

Comment: What is your insight?

Comment: @TimmyJim his insight doesn't apply towards it anymore. In his previous question, he indicated that he'd defeated Rom, which is a major turning point in the game.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As to **what** causes this:

Based on [this list](http://www.giantbomb.com/forums/bloodborne-650327/this-is-exactly-what-insight-does-1771080/) of Insight-related audio and visual changes:

> 60 Insight
>
> A crying baby can be heard occasionally.

However, these changes lose their insight requirement once you have defeated Rom, which, based on your [previous post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/290636/where-is-the-best-place-to-farm-blood-vials-in-bloodborne), I know you have.

---

Now, for the **why**:

The reason is lore-related, and I'll try to describe it as I understand it roughly, keeping spoilers to a minimum.

The theme of birth and rebirth is present all though Bloodborne, and becomes clearer the further you progress. The description for the [1/3 Umbilical Cord](http://bloodborne.wiki.fextralife.com/One+Third+of+Umbilical+Cord) items will best answer your question, but may spoil things, so don't read if you're worried about having things spoiled for you.

> From what I've come to understand, the crying baby is a manifestation of the birth of a Great One's surrogate child, possibly Mergo.

Once you have completed the game (or your desire for a plot/lore explanation becomes overwhelming), I highly recommend you read ["The Paleblood Hunt"](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JL5acskAT_2t062HILImBkV8eXAwaqOj611mSjK-vZ8/edit). It delves into the lore in extreme depth and does its best to explain a lot of mysteries.

Comment: I have defeated Rom and I have about 10 Insight. I heard somewhere that over 15 Insight makes the game more difficult, does it mean that now any number of Insight makes the game more difficult?

Comment: @jgadoury Having more Insight *always* made the game more difficult, but there were certain thresholds that would allow you to see the world for what it really was prior to defeating Rom. After beating Rom, these thresholds disappear and you are exposed to everything, but higher Insight gives you less Frenzy resistance always.